# Can I sync a Zumero client to a public facing server with only an eval key?

Tags: zumero

I'm guessing from this section that I need to have an activation key in order to sync to a public facing server but I can't find anything explicitly says that:

http://zumero.com/faq/#createactivation

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.  But if you're syncing to port 8080, you may need to open that up in your firewall.